# ElasticSearch did not pull whole SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, windows-7-x64

I'm testing out setting up ElasticSearch with existing SQL table (from SQL Server) following this [instruction](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/Step-by-step-recipe-for-setting-up-the-river-with-SQL-Server). Everything works fine and I've tested out on some small tables and things work like a charm.

And now when I tested on a slightly bigger table, which has 2,825,077 rows. When I load it into ElasticSearch using this statement using Sense Chrome Plugin and click run:

```
PUT _river/scorecards_river/_meta
{
    "type":"jdbc",
    "jdbc": {
        "driver":"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
        "url":"jdbc:sqlserver://SQLSERVERNAME;databaseName=Test",
        "user":"username",
        "password":"password",
        "sql":"select ID as _id, IP as ip from testtable",
        "strategy":"simple",
        "index": "test",
        "type":"product",
        "bulk_size":100,
        "max_retries":5,
        "max_retries_wait":"30s",
        "max_bulk_requests":5,
        "bulk_flush_interval":"5s"
    }
}
```

In console it brings up all BULK insert info, and seems like it fully load all data.

[image]

But when I do a quick count in Sense:

```
GET jdbc/jdbc/_count
```

It gave me:

```
{
   "count": 1488226,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   }
}
```

I wasn't able to find any related information on explaining so, anyone has any idea why this happened?

some background: I'm on Windows 7, and ES version is elasticsearch 1.4.2, alsp using sqljdbc4, elasticsearch-river-jdbc-2.2.3

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the elasticsearch-river-jdbc version is the problem, after remove old driver and installed new one from [here](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc#installation) with latest version, 1.4.0.8. It loads data successfully now.